# React - Dont call method if event is fired from an element currently rendered by this component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I currently have this code

```
import { Tooltip } from "Toolkit";
import React, { Component } from "react";

export default class TooltipWrapper extends Component {
    constructor() {
        super();

        this.handleWindowClick = this.handleWindowClick.bind(this);
        this.toggleTooltip = this.toggleTooltip.bind(this);
        this.onTooltipClosed = this.onTooltipClosed.bind(this);
    }

    state = {
        show: false,
    };

    componentDidMount() {
        document.body.addEventListener('click', this.handleWindowClick);
    }

    componentWillUnmount() {
        document.body.removeEventListener('click', this.handleWindowClick);
    }

    onTooltipClosed() {
        this.setState({
            show: false,
        });
    }

    handleWindowClick(event) {
        if (this.state.show) {
            this.setState({
                show: false,
            });
        }
    }

    toggleTooltip(event) {
        this.setState({
            show: !this.state.show,
        });
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <Tooltip
                open={this.state.show}
                tip={this.props.tip}
                onClose={this.onTooltipClosed}
                {...this.props}
            >
                <div onClick={this.toggleTooltip}>{this.props.children}</div>
            </Tooltip>
        );
    }
}
```

I am having an issue where the `handleWindowClick` function is being called before `toggleTooltip`. As a result whenever i click on a tooltip to close it, the `handleWindowClick` sets the state to false first always and then after `toggleTooltip` opens it again.

The `handleWindowClick` function works as expected when i am clicking outside of a tooltip in order to close it and also works when i click on another tooltip, it closes.

In handleWindowClick I think the solution is that I don't want to do anything if i have clicked anywhere in the tooltip which I have currently rendered in that instance. Any ideas on how to do this?

Thanks

Comment: what react version you are using ?

Comment: Im currently using 15.5.0

Comment: In that case, I think you just need `event.stopPropagation()` in your toggleTooltip function ?

Answer (score 0):

TLDR:

```
handleWindowClick(event) {
    if (event.handledByTooltip !== this && this.state.show) {
        this.setState({
            show: false,
        });
    }
}

toggleTooltip(event) {
    event.handledByTooltip = this;
    this.setState({
        show: !this.state.show,
    });
}
```

Due to the way events bubble up the DOM hierarchy, `toggleTooltip` should be called bofore `handleWindowClick`. In each of those functions, you can examine the event in order to decide what action to take.

One of the useful properties of the event is `target` which is a reference to the element that was actually clicked on. Unfortunately, this will usually be one of the children of element instead of the element we actually care about, so `if (event.target === myToolTipElement)` will not usually work. You would need to look at the parent of `event.target` and that parent and so on.

You could use `event.stopPropagation()` to stop the event from bubbling any higher than your tooltip, but that should only be used as a last resort, because most events usually bubble all the way to the top and other code might depend on that.

If you call `event.preventDefault()` in the tooltip handler then `event.defaultPrevented` will be true in the window handler. Great, you can communicate from the tooltip handler to the window handler! But `preventDefault` is meant for communicating to the browser that you have handled the event and that it shouldn't do what it was going to do, so that's not quite right for this problem either.

The idea of communicating that a tooltip handler has already seen the event is a good one, but you also need to know *which* tooltip handled the event. So, in `toggleTooltip` you can annotate the `event` with some value that identifies the tooltip that handled it (I used `this` which is unique to the tooltip) and in `handleWindowClick` you can compare the values to see if *this* tooltip handled the event already. That way, if you click on one tooltip, the `handleWindowClick` from any other handler will still do it's job.

Answer (score -1):

Example : https://codepen.io/centrodph/pen/KxKKrY?editors=0011

```
import { Tooltip } from "Toolkit";
import React, { Component } from "react";

export default class TooltipWrapper extends Component {
    constructor() {
        super();

        this.handleWindowClick = this.handleWindowClick.bind(this);
        this.toggleTooltip = this.toggleTooltip.bind(this);
        this.onTooltipClosed = this.onTooltipClosed.bind(this);
    }

    state = {
        show: false,
    };

    componentDidMount() {
        document.body.addEventListener('click', this.handleWindowClick);
    }

    componentWillUnmount() {
        document.body.removeEventListener('click', this.handleWindowClick);
    }

    onTooltipClosed() {
        this.setState({
            show: false,
        });
    }

    handleWindowClick(event) {
        //you can ask for the target also
        // event.currentTarget != `you toggle click` then ...
        if (this.state.show) {
            this.setState({
                show: false,
            });
        }
    }

    toggleTooltip(event) {
        this.setState({
            show: true,
        });
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <Tooltip
                open={this.state.show}
                tip={this.props.tip}
                onClose={this.onTooltipClosed}
                {...this.props}
            >
                <div onClick={this.toggleTooltip}>{this.props.children}</div>
            </Tooltip>
        );
    }
}
```